# How to publish shapefiles to web with no programming required?

Tags: shapefile, web-mapping

I am new to GIS web development.

I do not have any programming background and I want all the maps that I design in GIS (shapefiles, using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3) to be published on the web.

Please tell me the direct or easy way to do this?

Comment: Using ArcGIS Server (at cost but the easy way) by publishing your mxd +data to the ArcGIS server.

Comment: PSU's [Cloud and Server GIS course](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/cloudGIS/) should give you a good introduction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just go to [www.mangomap.com](http://www.mangomap.com). You'll have your shapefiles turned into web maps in minutes with all the functionality you could want - search/print/identify/pushpins/queries/templates etc all without writing a single line of code..

Also you can add labels to you map and customise the symbols of point layers.

Best of all it's currently free!

**Disclaimer**: I am the founder of MangoMap.

Comment: yesss... thanks alot for this answer... I wanted the same though my senior rejected this idea sayin that we need a database so that there's no choking and shapefiles in this way may b choked since we have to handle larger data sets. But my question has been answered. thanks... :)

Comment: MangoMap only uses shapefiles to accept the data, under the hood it's using PostgreSQL/PostGIS. I've seen the global tree height data loaded into it so it's capable of handling absolutely massive datasets.

Comment: ahan, thanx a lot for this info. I hope I get my stuff done using this... :)

Answer (score 6):

Given the constraints of:

1. the ArcGIS family of products,
2. No programming required,
3. Simple and Direct,
4. Little or No Cost

-- I think best bet is ArcGIS Online for sharing maps and data on web.

With a free personal account, you get 2G of storage or you can have a paid account that will allow you to create groups and group members and other benefits. With a paid account watch out for geocoding large datasets and creating tiled data sets.

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/features/free-personal-account

Comment: Thank everyone. Dear Awesomo I just tried what you mentioned. yes it works but it is very limited. Means, editing tools plus giving different colors and symbology etc. Is it possible to edit and create stuff in this as I do in arcgis...?

Comment: each point feature can be identified but can i label all of them in this or change their symbol, more symbol options...?

Comment: ArcGIS Online doesn't support labels currently. Also, I think you will need ArcMap 10.1 in order to directly publish shapefiles with ArcMap's symbology. Otherwise, symbology is limited.

Answer (score 3):

There are also [Tilemill app](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) which able to read

> ESRI Shapefile, KML, GeoJSON, GeoTIFF, PostGIS, CSV

And publish result to Mapbox cloud service

[GisCloud](http://www.giscloud.com) also allows to upload and publish geo data quite easily

Comment: You can use the TileMill Connect feature to [Export Your ArcGIS MXD Projects to TileMill](http://mapbox.com/blog/announcing-arc2earth-sync/), (recommend watching the video posted in [this announcement](http://mapbox.com/blog/connecting-arcgis-tilemill/).

Answer (score 2):

http://cartodb.com/ just upload the spatial data and work around to customize. if you know sql its added advantage but still you can work without it also ..

Create dynamic maps, analyze and build location-aware and geospatial applications with your data using the power using the power of PostGIS in the cloud.